# Getting blank screen from packaged air desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, screen

I am developing an as3 application intended to be published with AIR.
I use the 4.6 version of Flex SDK with the flash builder plugin for eclipse.
I can launch/debug my app via eclipse without any problems. I export a valid version of the app and get my air installer. When I install and launch my app, I get a blank screen...
I don't know how to debug this. It seems that I miss something in the publication configuration but I don't know what.
I have been searching the web for hours and didn't find any solution, hope somebody can help me here !

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What class is your TopLevelApplication? `Application`? `WindowedApplication`? I've experienced this issue before when using `Application`, but it always seems to resolve itself when using `WindowedApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

It simply was a real as3 error that didn't show up on debug mode...
When allowing the debug mode on the AIR application I learned that the property mouseChildren cannot be set on SimpleButton.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with my app and I finally found a way to display the error in the package app:

You just have to add a file named `debug` into your app/META-INF/AIR folder.

For detailed information see [Adobe Cookbook](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Show_debug_error_window_of_installed_AIR_applicati-13206.html).